# How to add Close All But Pinned command to Visual Studio 2010 menu or toolbar?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I've implemented the suggestions in Scott Hanselman's blog post [Simplify your Visual Studio 2010 Toolbar and Free Your Mind](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/SimplifyYourVisualStudio2010ToolbarAndFreeYourMind.aspx). Very cool.

Where can I find/execute the command "Close All But Pinned" that is part of Visual Studio Productivity Power Tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a two step process:

Create a Macro with the following

```
Public Module myToolbar
    Sub CloseAllButPinned()
        DTE.ExecuteCommand("Window.CloseAllButPinned")
    End Sub
End Module
```

Right click on your Toolbar, choose Customize, Add Command, Category Macro, choose MyMacros.myToolbar,CloseAllButPinned

Then click ModifySelection and give it an easy to remember name

Comment: Thank you.  how about assigning it to the context menu that comes up from right-clicking on the tab of an open document?  I saw elsewhere that the menu to modify is `Other Context Menus | Easy MDI Tool Window`.  Not sure if the fact that I have Resharper installed affects the context menu choice.  Cheers!

Comment: In VS2013, executing `dte.ExecuteCommand("Window.CloseAllButPinned");` shows Command is not valid.

Comment: It seems that Macro recording is not supported in visual studio 2012
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12062515/can-i-record-play-macros-in-visual-studio-2012-2013-2015

Answer (score 2):

You can assign a shortcut in `Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Keyboard`. Search for **Window.CloseAllButPinned** in the *Show commands containing:* textbox and assign your own key combination.

Similarly, you can execute that command in the "Go To Find Combo" small box, i.e. press Ctrl+/ then type "*>Window.CloseAllButPinned*", press Enter.

Comment: Excellent suggestion and implemented. However I would like toolbar option for those brain dead days :-)

Comment: I don't think it allows adding toolbars.. couldn't you simply add commands from a toolbar to the menu bar? There is also an option to begin a new group in the menubar so you can simulate a toolbar.